# How to use Selenium to repeatedly obtain content <Python>?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I am crawling text from [here](http://debate.org/opinions/is-global-climate-c%E2%80%A6). I need to repeatedly click on "Load More Arguments" to obtain all arguments listed on the page. Here is my code:

```
try:
    while True:
        link = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Load More Arguments")))

        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(link).perform()
        link.click()
        time.sleep(3) #wait for the update to occurr so the page loads"new arguments for you"
        print(driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML;"))

        if not (link):
            break
finally:
    None
```

Here is the error:

```
File "debate.py", line 42, in <module>
  EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Load More Arguments")))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.44.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
  raise TimeoutException(message)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I do obtain the arguments listed on the page but I think my code is a bit strange, especially in the loop. I think I need something to replace "if not" like "not clickable". Could you please give me some suggestion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, `if not link:` is not the condition you want. If this condition were ever to be true, then neither your `move_to_element` nor the `click` would work, because there is nothing between them and your `if not link:` test that can alter `link` from referring to an element be `None` (or some other false value). The element reference that `link` contains could become *stale* but this kind of issue generates a specific exception. There's no magic that turns a stale reference to `None`.

In all likelihood, the timeout event that you currently run into is the indication that you are done. I would expect that the button to load more arguments would be unclickable (because it is no longer present or because it is disabled) once you've loaded everything. (I cannot verify this, as the link you provided gets me to a page that does not illustrate the problem.)

If you break on the exception, you can exit your loop. This also takes care of the case where there are no arguments yet or there are not *enough* arguments to warrant the presence of the button:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

[....]

while True:
    try:
        link = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Load More Arguments")))
    except TimeoutException:
        break
    [...]
```

A few notes:

1. The outer `try... finally` block does not seem to do anything.
2. Usually, you can move and click a link in one operation `link.click()` should work without the `ActionChains`. There are some rather rare cases where you need to perform a move before the click.
3. You should replace your `time.sleep` call with an explicit wait that inspects the state of the page to determine when the arguments have finished loading.